# How to assign values from a Result Set to fields in a Form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query that returns an N Result Set. I want to use this query to assign values for a Field on a Form OnCurrent. Right now, my error says it is `Cannot perform this operation. Run-Time Error 3032`

So if I have, say 5 records being returned in my query and I want to go one-by-one and assign a Column in my Form (Datasheet View) with the value.

My method looks like:

```
Private Sub ConfigureScore()
  Dim resultSet As DAO.RecordSet
  Set resultSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyQuery")
  If Not (resultSet.EOF And resultSet.BOF) Then
   resultSet.MoveFirst
   Do Until resultSet.EOF = True
   Me.Field.Value = resultSet![Name]
   resultSet.Update
   resultSet.MoveNext
 Loop
 End If
 resultSet.Close
 Set resultSet = Nothing
End Sub
```

So, in my `MyQuery`, the value returned is Name it looks like `SELECT Name FROM...`. The query only returns one column and I want to take these values and populate my Form's `Field` Column.

Comment: Why not using a bound form?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create multiple rows in an unbound form.

The way to populate the "rows" in a form is to set the form's *RecordSource* to a table or query ("bind the form") and "bind" controls like textboxes in the details section of the form to fields of that query setting their *ControlSource* property to the name of a field of that query. No VBA needed for that.

In your scenario, the form should be bound to `MyQuery` and the details section should contain a textbox that is bound to the field `Name`.